# Meaning of 'CVers'?

Tags: discussion, comments, terminology

I have seen this used on a few posts and tried searching what it stands for. Sure it will be glaringly obvious once someone tells me, but what does 'CVers' mean?

Answer (score 4):

CV is short for "close vote" - contrast that with DV (which can be downvote or delete vote). A CVer is someone who casts a close vote.